# cupy matrix multiplication n number of times

Tags: python-3.x, cupy

I need to multiply two matrices a large number of times, I am using CUPY. I am doing it like this

```
import cupy as cp
import time

iterations = 9680000
a = cp.random.rand(44,20)
b = cp.random.rand(20,1)

def ab(a,b,iterations):
for i in range(iterations):
    cp.matmul(a,b,out=None)

t1 = time.time()
ab(a,b,iterations)
t2 = time.time()
total = t2-t1
```

In the above code for loops takes much time, I know this shouldn't be done like that. How should I rewrite it with cupy so that the for loop doesn't become a bottleneck

Comment: Are the matrices to multiply the same or different at every iteration? In the above code, they look the same, but then can't you cache the result?

Comment: matrices are different at every iteration

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of `a` and `b` matrices that you want to multiply together, both numpy and cupy can do the [matmul operation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) more efficiently if you "stack" the matrices, rather than loop through them.

With respect to cupy, the matrix "stacks" still have to fit in GPU memory, so this needs to be taken into account. If you have so many matrices that the stacks will not fit in GPU memory, then you would need to find a way to break the work into pieces, and loop through the pieces.  But each piece could be a stack of matrices to be multiplied.

Here's an example with a smaller set of matrices, showing the difference:

Your method (iterations reduced to 1000000):

```
$ cat t3.py
import cupy as cp
import time

iterations = 1000000
a = cp.random.rand(44,20)
b = cp.random.rand(20,1)

def ab(a,b,iterations):
  for i in range(iterations):
    cp.matmul(a,b,out=None)

t1 = time.time()
ab(a,b,iterations)
cp.cuda.Device(0).synchronize()
t2 = time.time()
total = t2-t1
print(total)
$ python t3.py
28.173577785491943
$
```

Stacked method (iterations reduced to 1000000):

```
$ cat t4.py
import cupy as cp
import time

iterations = 1000000
loops = 10
stack = iterations//loops
a = cp.random.rand(stack,44,20)
b = cp.random.rand(stack,20,1)

def ab(a,b,loops):
  for i in range(loops):
    cp.matmul(a,b,out=None)

t1 = time.time()
ab(a,b,loops)
cp.cuda.Device(0).synchronize()
t2 = time.time()
total = t2-t1
print(total)
$ python t4.py
0.8356013298034668
$
```